# Can you recreate this fractal I randomly made?

Tags: geometry, algorithm, cellular-automata

This fractal looks relatively simple, but how would you generate it?

[image: Triangular fractal]

On a smaller scale:

[image: Zoomed in triangular fractal]

I made it using a 1D cellular automaton with a four cell neighborhood:

[image: diagram showing the cells that contribute to each generation of the automatin - 3 from previous generation and 1 from the one before that]

```
 ..|-|..    2 generations back
|-||-||-|   1 generation back
 ..|-|..    current generation
```

But since there are $65536$ possible rules for this CA, and I don't remember this particular one, it's unlikely I will find it again.

For the Sierpiski triangle we have many different ways to generate it (see [this page](http://www.oftenpaper.net/sierpinski.htm) for example).

> I would really like it if the answer contained a generated fractal. I would also love to know another method of generating it, not related to cellular automata.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? There are three different questions here.

Comment: @Deusovi, any algorithm which creates this fractal. I edited

Comment: Do you have any 1:1 scale (1 cell per pixel) versions of the image?

Comment: @2012rcampion, done. But I would really like some rules not related to cellular automata as well

Comment: What do those quoted strings mean?

Comment: @celtschk, see the new image for clarification

Comment: I found this rule given as an example [in Mathematica's documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellularAutomaton.html)! (look under Scope > Higher-Order Rules)  They call it "Rule 150R—the second-order reversible mod 2 rule"

Comment: @2012rcampion, thank you for the reference. I still hope for a simple geometric construction for this fractal

Comment: Ive wanted to understand automata for some time. Could you explain in simple terms how the shape is built? I dont mean the riddles answer. I mean can you make the question clearer so a non-automata-knowledged individual can attempt it?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Start by coloring in one pixel. Then move down one row, and color in every pixel that has an odd number of pixels in the four closest squares above it. Repeat over and over.

Comment: And then if I imagine correclty, certain pixels "die" as one of the answers put it? This "dying condition" being what determines the unique shape?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, every pixel which doesn't meet the 'living' condition, dies

Comment: '[...] there are 65536 possible rules for this CA [...]', according to OP. How do you get that number actually? Why isn't it 2^4=16, the number of possible state combinations of the 4 cells in the neighbourhood?

Comment: @elias, there are $16$ possible states for *parent* cells. There are two possible states of the *active* cell for each configuration of the parent cells. Ergo, we have $2^{16}=65536$ possible rules

Comment: I don't get your point, sorry. Isn't the state of the active cell determined only by the states of the parent cells?

Comment: @elias, maybe you could read the first paragrath of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryCellularAutomaton.html, it explains why there are 256 rules for elementary CA with 3 parent cells. The same logic applies here

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you very much. It became clear after seeing the picture and reading the first sentences there. Sorry for my slow-mindedness!

Comment: Duplicate the OP posted on another site: **http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127480/35531**

Comment: @mbomb007, this is not a duplicate. The questions are completely different. Question you linked was made after this and specifically asks about Mathematica implementation of a particular method of creating this fractal

Comment: I meant "related". Essentially though, both were asking to make the same fractal.

Comment: This question inspired me to create this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.admdev.fractalviewer

Comment: @Adam, great work! I will definitely install it. I love cellular automata, but I'm not a programmer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The pattern is self-similar, and can be formed by repeatedly scaling and rotating copies of itself:

> [image]

An alternate dissection that fits in a diamond:

> [image]

Comment: What is the minimal starting element?

Comment: @YuriyS Any shape you want; since it is eventually shrunken to a point it doesn't matter.  I used a triangle covering the upper half.

Comment: The second case is more clear to me. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a nice way to derive this self-similarity relation from the rule?

Comment: @xnor Not that I know of, I just figured it out by observation.

Comment: Thank you again. I finally understood how to get the first case. It is much easier your way, than the method I used in my own 'answer'. I started with a rotated square.

Answer (score 17):

There are only 16 different possible state combinations of the four ancestor cells, and you can find them all in the image, so there is a unique answer.

The rule is as follows:

> The new cell lives if there is an odd number of live ancestor cells.

Comment: I must admit, this is a pretty neat way to find the rule, using a random 'snapshot' of a CA pattern

Answer (score 8):

I think the rule is:

> A cell is black if and only if an odd number of the four "parent" cells is black.

Answer (score 7):

This is by no means an answer, but using @2012rcampion's interpretation, I wanted to illustrate how this fractal can be generated using top-down approach, starting from a single element:

```
   /\  /\
  /  \/  \
 /   /\   \
/   /  \   \
\  /    \  /
 \/      \/
 /\      /\
/  \/\/\/  \
\  /\/\/\  /
 \/      \/
```

> [image]

Step one:

> [image]

Step two:

> [image]

Step three:

> [image]

The element is scaled down by a factor of $2$ on each step and added to any place we can. I omitted some of the elements, which didn't fit on the picture.

Answer (score 5):

Simply because I posted some code for a similar puzzle a few minutes ago, I may as well post some Excel VBA code to generate this one too:

> ```
> Sub RunIt()
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     Dim r As Long
>     Dim c As Long
>     Dim cnt As Integer
>     Cells.Interior.Color = xlAutomatic
>     Cells(2, 8000).Interior.Color = vbRed
>     r = 3
>     Do While r < 500
>         For c = 8000 - r To 8000 + r
>             cnt = 0
>             If Cells(r - 2, c + 0).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 1
>             If Cells(r - 1, c - 1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 1
>             If Cells(r - 1, c + 0).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 1
>             If Cells(r - 1, c + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 1
>             If cnt = 1 Or cnt = 3 Then
>                 Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = vbRed
>             End If
>         Next
>         r = r + 1
>     Loop
>     Cells(1, 8000).Select
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
> End Sub
> ```